# phpmyadmin equivalent for IOS?

Tags: ios, mysql, mobile, phpmyadmin

Do you know a phpmyadmin equivalent for IOS  (iphone and ipad) ?
I found MySQL Mobile Database Client By Glimpse I/O LLC, but I am not sure if it does the same thing, 
or Navicat ?

thank you

Comment: phpmyadmin is a web app installed on a web server, so apart from possible browser issues, it should work on most devices.

Comment: thanks but I am looking for an IOS  app

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mysql-querydb-client/id576948046?mt=8 ?

I quote from its description: "The easiest way to view data from your MySQL databases on your iPhone or iPad!"

Comment: thanks but it works only with queries , thats not what I am looking for